# How do per-site Metas differ from Meta Stack Exchange, and where should I go to ask my question?

Tags: support, meta, per-site-meta, faq-proposed

How do per-site metas, such as Meta Writers Stack Exchange or Meta Stack Overflow differ from the general Meta Stack Exchange?

Where should I go to ask my question?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Comment: Related: [Why are there different meta sites for different Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140583/why-are-there-different-meta-sites-for-different-stack-exchange-sites)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**How do per-site metas differ from Meta Stack Exchange?**

Meta Stack Exchange (MSE) differs from each per-site meta in a few distinct ways:

- On normal per-site metas, your reputation matches the reputation from the main site. MSE has its own distinct reputation.
- There is usually a (very low but non-trivial) reputation requirement to post on a per-site meta (the "[Participate In Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)" privilege) (except for asking about your own posts specifically); there is no such requirement on MSE.

...that's it.

**Where should I go to ask my question?**

If you have a question about:

- a general policy for all Stack Exchange sites
- a bug/issue affecting all Stack Exchange sites
- the technology that powers the Stack Exchange network

...then you're in the right place. If you have a question about a specific Stack Exchange site's function and policy, or of a specific question on a specific site, then please consider asking this question on the per-site meta.

Please do not ask questions concerning Stack Overflow specifically on Meta Stack Exchange. These questions belong on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). The fact that there are old Stack Overflow-specific questions here is because this site previously allowed such questions - these are now in the process of being closed accordingly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you remove that paragraph? I think that paragraph does good there; we get SO-specific questions here on a routine basis.

Comment: @Sonic I didn't really like the paragraph's wording, then thought about editing it briefly before deciding that it didn't pertain to the question asked. It's important information, but I'm not sure it's important here. I'm relatively ambivalent, though. If you think it belongs, I'm okay with that.