# What is child meta in StackExchange?

Tags: support

I saw word called child meta in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/362477.

Then I searched about it. I saw a few questions which related child meta.

But I could not find what is child meta?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do per-site Metas differ from Meta Stack Exchange, and where should I go to ask my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229789/how-do-per-site-metas-differ-from-meta-stack-exchange-and-where-should-i-go-to)

Comment: No it's not @gnat. This question is not about the difference, just asking what it is.

Answer (score 9):

A child-meta is the meta site attached to a specific Q&A site.

For example - [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the child-meta of [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Similarly, for any specific `<site>`.stackexchange.com, there is a child meta `<site>`.meta.stackexchange.com.